# Xamarin - Does Android Drawable Exist?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, resources, drawable

In a Xamarin Forms (3.0) application, what method(s) would I use to tell if a drawable resource exists in my Android project from shared project code?

In iOS, I can use NSFileManager to see if the file exists in my iOS project's "Resources" folder:

```
#if __IOS__
private bool DoesImageExist(string image)
{
    //WORKS
    return Foundation.NSFileManager.DefaultManager.FileExists(image);
}
#endif
```

In Android, I thought it should be part of the Assembly Resources, but that just returns my App.xaml file.

```
#if __ANDROID__
private bool DoesImageExist(string image)
{
    //DOES NOT WORK
    if(MyApp.Current?.GetType() is Type type)
        foreach (var res in Assembly.GetAssembly(type).GetManifestResourceNames())
        {
            if (res.Equals(image, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                return true;
        }
    return false;
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to specifically check if a drawable exists by name in android would work like something this:

```
#if __ANDROID__
public bool DoesImageExist(string image)
{
    var context = Android.App.Application.Context;
    var resources = context.Resources;
    var name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(image);
    int resourceId = resources.GetIdentifier(name, "drawable", context.PackageName);

    return resourceId != 0;
}
#endif
```

If your code is in a pcl or .net standard assembly, you will have to create an abstraction. Some kind of Ioc library works well for this. You can also have Android or iOS implement the abstract interface and make that available as a singleton somewhere. It's not as elegant, but it would work.

Basically you would implement something like this:

```
public interface IDrawableManager
{
    bool DoesImageExist(string path);
}
```

Then have two implementations:

```
public class DroidDrawableManager : IDrawableManager
{
        var context = Android.App.Application.Context;
        var resources = context.Resources;
        var name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(image);
        int resourceId = resources.GetIdentifier(name, "drawable", context.PackageName);

        return resourceId != 0;
}

public class IOSDrawableManager : IDrawableManager
{
    public bool DoesImageExist(string image)
    {
        return Foundation.NSFileManager.DefaultManager.FileExists(image);
    }
}
```

I've uploaded a working sample to github:

https://github.com/curtisshipley/ResourceExists

Comment: Looks like we're on the right path, but I'm getting `Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'defPackage' of 'Resources.GetIdentifier(string, string, string)'`

Comment: `resources.GetIdentifier(image, "drawable", context.PackageName);` returns nothing

Comment: You may have to remove the extension.

Comment: Adding the package name, and removing the extension works for me. I've uploaded a working sample to github.

Comment: Your sample works, which answers the core question "How to", but I still can't make it work in my app, even rebuilding your sample as a DLL and referencing it does not work. My PackageName matches my project's Android Manifest. Any ideas?

Comment: Not off the top of my head. It could build be a number of reasons. If you wanted to post the code on github, I could take a look.